# C# Override with different parameters?

Tags: c#, .net, overriding

Here is an example of what I am looking to do.

```
public class A
{
    public virtual void DoSomething(string a)
    {
      // perform something
    }
}
public class B : A
{
    public Override void DoSomething(string a, string b)
    {
      // perform something slightly different using both strings
    }
}
```

So I want to override DoSomething from class A and allow it to pass a second parameter. Is this possible?

Comment: No, it isn't overriding. It is overloading.

Comment: You are just creating a second overload to the first method. You can declare it as `virtual` if you want to allow it being overridden in derived classes but it isn't overriding anything itself.

Comment: Just Impossible! The override method must have the same signature.

Comment: If it were possible, what would you expect this code to do? `A a = new B(); a.DoSomething("");` What should be the second parameter passed to `B.DoSomething`? Doesn't make sense for me.

Answer (score 18):

When overriding a `virtual` method, you must keep the original "contract" of the method, which in your case is a `string a` variable.

In order to do what you want, you can create a virtual *overload* which takes two strings:

```
public class A
{
    public virtual void DoSomething(string a)
    {
      // perform something
    }
    public virtual void DoSomething(string a, string b)
    {
      // perform something
    }
}

public class B : A
{
    public override void DoSomething(string a, string b)
    {
      // perform something slightly different using both strings
    }
}
```

If what you want is to accept N strings in your method, you can use the `params` keyword:

```
public class A
{
    public virtual void DoSomething(params string[] allStrings)
    {
      // Do something with the first string in the array
      // perform something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Slight necro, but when you overload you can call the original method from the new one.

so

```
public class B : A {

    public virtual void DoSomething (string a, string b) {
        base.DoSomething(_a);
        //Do B things here
    }
}
```

This allows you to modify the method instead of completely redoing it :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a way. It requires some code though. You create a master class fex. 'MachineParams'. Then create subclasses like 'MachineParamsGeneral', 'MachineParamsDetail'.

Your function can now be like:

```
public override void Setup(MachineParams p)
{
// since you know what subclass this is inside, you can simple cast
MachineParamsGeneral g = (MachineParamsGeneral)p;
float paramExample = p.paramExample;
}
```

You need to consider if this solution is "handy" enough for your scale.

A second solution:

```
public override void Setup(params object[] p ..)
{
// you need to know the arrangement of values inside the object array
float x = (float)p[0]; // not strictly speaking type-safe
}
```

Comment: Also, if you do something like making the class that implements the various Setup methods generic i.e. with a TMachineParams generic with the constraint "where TMachineParams : MachineParams", and include this TMachineParams in the abstract base class for the derived classes that implement Setup, you can also have the params object handled in a way that you don't need to cast

Answer (score 1):

```
public class BaseClass
{
    //the '= null' makes it that the subsequent classes doesn't necessarily need to pass parameters
    public virtual void InitializeOrWhatever(object[] parameters = null)
    {
    }

    //this method allows that others can check their parameters to se if it's the right type
    public static bool VerifyParameter<T>(object obj, out T cast)
    {
        cast = (T)obj;
            if (cast != null)
                return true;
            else
            {
                ParametersError(typeof(T));
                return false;
            }
        }

    //this method prints out a massage if the type doesn't match. Also can be changed from outside classes
    public static void ParametersError(Type t, string addition = "")
            => print($"Parameters sent on {t} initialization are not correct!\n{addition}")
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    float Number;
    bool Used;

    public override void InitializeOrWhatever(object[] parameters = null)
    {
        //executes the base method. Important if the parent class must execute something first
        base.Initialize(controller, parameters);

        //custom message sent from derived class
        if (parameters == null)
        {
            ParametersError(this.GetType(), "No parameters sent!");
            return;
        }

        if (VerifyParameter(parameters[0], out float number))
            Number = number;

        if (VerifyParameter(parameters[1], out bool used))
            Used = used;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

No, this won't work. When overriding the methods needs to have the same prototype.

Comment: Is there any way of doing this? I am creating a 2 types of linked lists and would like the second to have a priority parameter when adding to the list.

Comment: You should just define the new method in the second class (I mean in class B). This new method will have two parameters, and then this new method can call the original method, this way: base.DoSometing("..."); Methods in your derived classes can call methods from your base classes with base.<MethodName>. This way you can reuse the existing code to some extent.

Answer (score 0):

No, this would be overloading.  Since the logic would be 'slightly different' it sounds like you would need two different methods anyway?  You could put your similar logic in a 3rd method and call that from both `DoSomething(string A)` and `DoSomething(string A, string B)`