# C# Override with different child parameters (Same Parent)?

Tags: c#, overriding

Here is an example of what I am looking to do.

```
public class ParentA {}
public class ChildA : ParentA 
{
  public string x;
}

public class A
{
    public virtual void DoSomething(Parent a)
    {
      // perform something
    }
}
public class B : A
{
    public Override void DoSomething(Child a)
    {
      // perform something slightly different using both strings
       a.x = "something";
    }
}
```

but turn out I got an error with "No Suitable Method found to Override".

So I want to override DoSomething from class A and pass a different set of child class parameter. Is this possible?

Comment: No, it's not. Because `A myVar = new B(); myVar.DoSomething(someParentObjectOrOtherChildClassInstance);` should be legal.

Comment: Welcome. You cannot change the signature of a method when overriding it. You have to use `Parent a` in class `B`.

Comment: No, you can't - and it's worth thinking why. What would you expect to happen if someone wrote: `A something = new B(); something.DoSomething(new Parent());`? What method would you expect to be called, and with what argument?

Comment: Why `override`? Just create another overload. Is your intent to have `List<A>` and you want to put instance of `B` inside?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# - Change argument type of override method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36101049/c-sharp-change-argument-type-of-override-method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you override something, the signature of the method has to be the same.

So in your case, you can do something like this

```
public class Parent { }
public class Child : Parent
{
    public string x;
}

public class A
{
    public virtual void DoSomething(Parent a)
    {
        // perform something
    }
}
public class B : A
{
    public override void DoSomething(Parent a)
    {
        if (a is Child child)
        {
        // perform something slightly different using both strings
            child.x = "something";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure exactly what you're trying to accomplish, however generics may help you:

```cs
public class Parent { }
public class Child : Parent
{
    public string x;
}

public class A<T> : Parent where T : Parent
{
    public virtual void DoSomething(T a)
    {
    }
}

public class B : A<Child> // Child could also be Parent here
{
    public override void DoSomething(Child a)
    {
        a.x = "test";
    }
}
```