# C# architecture question when iterating through different objects inherited from the same class

Tags: c#, inheritance, 3d

Sorry for the title I really found no clear way to explain it shortly.

I'm doing a project where I generate `Spheres` and `Triangles`, I made them inherit from the class `Objet` and stored them in a `List<Objet>`.
Now I need to iterate through these objects (with a `foreach`), and I want to use their function `getNormale(???)` in this loop.
The problem is that the class Sphere needs two parameters in it and the class Triangle doesn't...

I found 2 ways but I don't know which one to use, and if there are better ways to do:

1. Put abstract function `getNormale(u, v)` in class `Objet` and override it, the problem will be that `Triangle.getNormale(u,v)` doesn't really need those parameters.
2. Put `Sphere` and `Triangle` in two different lists, `List<Sphere>` and `List<Triangle>` iterating through each one of them and calling `getNormale(u,v)` and `getNormale()` respectively. I don't really like this answer because if I decide to add other classes inheriting `Objet` I will need to modify this loop...

Comment: Apply the parameters in the constructor by creating the figures

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `getNormale` requires 2 arguments for `Sphere` and 0 for `Triangle` they aren't really related enough to store the implementation of `getNormale` in the `Objet` class. If there are multiple classes that allow an empty parameter list for `getNormale`, you can use a sub-class for that, likewise if there are multiple classes that allow 2 parameters for `getNormale` that could also be its own subclass.

You could use the `is` operator to differentiate the two objects, and cast them to their appropriate class before calling the appropriate `getNormale` method on them

```cs
foreach(var shape in shapes)
{
  string normale;
  if(shape is Triangle)
  {
    normale = ((Triange)shape).getNormale();
  }
  else if(shape is Sphere)
  {
    normale = ((Sphere)shape).getNormale(u,v);
  }
  Console.WriteLine($"Normale: {normale}");
}
```

Alternatively, if `u`, and `v` were parameters that are related to the object itself (maybe u is circumference, and v is the radius), and you could know them at initialization, they should be stored as fields within the `Sphere` class. In that case, you would be able to call `getNormale` without any parameters, as your `Sphere` class would already have access to `u` and `v`

Answer (score 1):

You should aim to be able to iterate your collection as the base class Objet, and be able to call GetNormale() on every object (or use conditional logic to determine whether you have a Sphere and call the more specific method from the more specialised derived class).

In C# use the 'virtual' keyword for a method in a base class that can be overridden, with the 'override' keyword used to declare the method in the derived class (if you have a similar method with a different signature in the derived class, no need to override as will be treated as separate).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
                
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Objet o1 = new Objet("o");
        Sphere s1 = new Sphere("s", 10);
        Triangle t1 = new Triangle("t", 5);

        //  The collection type is Objet, but you can add derived types
        List<Objet> Objets = new List<Objet> { o1, s1, t1 };
        foreach (Objet o in Objets)
        {
            if (o.GetType().Name == "Sphere")
            {
                //  Could use 'if (o is Sphere)' ;)
                //  Special treatment for spheres
                Sphere s = (Sphere)o;
                s.GetNormale("Foo", "Bar");
            }
            else
            {
                //  Could just call this for every item
                o.GetNormale();
            }
        }
    }

    public class Objet
    {
        public string Name {get; set;}
    
        public Objet()
        {
        }
    
        public Objet(string name)
        {
            Name = name;    
        }

        public virtual void GetNormale() =>
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Objet prints: {0}", Name));
    }

    public class Triangle : Objet
    {
        public Triangle(string name, int side) : base(name)
        {
            Side = side;
        }
    
        public int Side {get; set;}
    
        //  Override the base class method
        public override void GetNormale() => 
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Triangle prints: {0}", Side));
    }

    public class Sphere : Objet
    {   
        public Sphere(string name, int circumference) : base(name)
        {
            Circumference = circumference;
        }
    
        public int Circumference {get; set;}

        //  Method signature is different, no override required
        public void GetNormale(string u, string v) =>
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Sphere prints: {0} & {1} & {2}", Circumference, u, v));
    }
}

//  Output
//  Objet prints: o
//  Sphere prints: 10 & Foo & Bar
//  Triangle prints: 5
```

This is known as 'polymorphism' where you can refer to an object as it's base class or derived class, depending on the circumstances.

Try reading up on the 'SOLID software design principles' which provide best-practice recommendations for class inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

You could check with cast and call it one way or another. Having virtual version in ancestor is not needed

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Shape> shapes = new List<Shape>();
        shapes.Add(new Triangle());
        shapes.Add(new Sphere());
        foreach (var shape in shapes)
        {
            _ = (shape is Triangle) ?
                ((Triangle)shape).GetNormale() :
                ((Sphere)shape).GetNormale(0, 0);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you really should create a abstract class named `shape` from which both `Spheres` and `Triangles` should inherit. Then add to the `shape` the method `getNormale()` creating `List<shape>` instead of `List<Object>`. Calling your base class `Object` is very confusing, and you should alwase make the base class describe the derived as accurately as possible

Now, for the problem itself. [It is impossible to override a method with different parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27547122/c-sharp-override-with-different-parameters) which is all your question really comes down to. This is why I would suggest, and this is really dependent on your parameter's use, to make the parameters into the constructor, and allow changing them via a `set` method / property.

This is a common way of dealing with such problems.

if the parameters are not fit to be a classes property's then you are out of lack. you will need to give up calling them together and rather stick to your `List<object>`, check the type for each object, and get the Normale accordinly, with each type having his own method and parameters. Never use redundant parameters. This can be very confusing.

```cs
double normale;
ICollection<Object> shapes = new List<object>();
//add you shapes here
foreach var shape in shapes{
 if(shape is Spheres)
 {
  normale = ((Spheres)shape).getNormale(u, v);
 }
else
{
 normale = ((Triangles )shape).getNormale();
}
}
```

Comment: Notice that the OP has a base class `Objet` (not `object`), I got confused at first too :)